# Как сделать проверку на наличие недопустимого слова?

Tags: c++, строки

Как сделать следующее:

Строка: `hello world test`

На выходе: `Ошибка`, потому что слово `test` не предусмотрено.

Мне нужно сделать ограничение, т. е. есть допустимые слова (например `hello` и `world`) и, если в строке найдено слово, которое не входит в список этих слов, написать `Ошибка`.

Comment: Я не совсем понял вопрос. Вам можно просто сравнить вашу строку со словом test с помощью регулярных выражений, например.

Comment: Нет,мне нужно сделать ограничение т.е. есть допустимые слова (например hello и world ) и если в строке найдено слово которое не входит в список этих слов,написать Ошибка

Comment: Найти все подстроки `test`. Это префикс функция или z  функция (алгоритмы есть на Википедии, например). Дальше проверить, что вокруг подстрок символ разделитель или конец строки.

Comment: @Daneil, вы с задачей определитесь. В комментарии и тексте вопроса вы рассказываете разные разачи. Проверить есть ли 1 слово в тексте и проверить есть ли у вас слова не из множества это разные задачи)

Comment: это модераторы изменили за ночь

Comment: Если нужно проверить на слова не из множества, то нужно разбить строку на слова, слова запихать в set, и дальше сравнить 2 множества.

Comment: @Daneil, по поводу правки №8 - чем вам помешали большая буква в начале, запятые и форматирование в последнем предложении?

Comment: Создайте множество ([пример](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/operator=/)) *допустимых слов*.  Далее, читайте свою строку по словам и проверяйте их наличие в этом множестве. Как только обнаружите слово, которого там нет, так и печатайте -- `"Ошибка"`